# How to clean Bundle files in Netbeans?

Tags: regex, netbeans, internationalization, bundle

In a web application developed with Netbeans there are some **Bundle.properties** files with translations. Lots of rows in these bundles refer to labels which are no more used.
How can I automate the process of find and remove them ?
Perhaps I can use a grep-like command with regex support to find all strings of type '*bundle.someLabel*', sort them and compare with the bundle content, deleting the rows in excess.

Is there a better way ?

Comment: I'm not aware of a Netbeans built-in solution for this, though I have sometimes the same need. If you write a plugin or script please share ;-)